MSAL 3.0 not returning accounts in Angular 17 after upgrading from 2.16.0
I recently upgraded @azure/msal-angular and @azure/msal-browser from version 2.16.0 to 3.0.0 in my Angular 17 project. Since the upgrade, I am unable to retrieve user accounts using this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts(), which now returns an empty array
Here's the updated Angular component code using an observer object with the `subscribe` method to address the RxJS deprecation warning:

import { MsalService, MsalBroadcastService, MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG, MsalGuardConfiguration  } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { InteractionType, InteractionStatus, PopupRequest, RedirectRequest, AuthenticationResult, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { b2cPolicies, msalConfig } from './auth/auth-config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private _destroying$ = new Subject<void>();
  private msalApp: PublicClientApplication;
  private isMsalInitialized: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    @Inject(MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG) private msalGuardConfig: MsalGuardConfiguration,
    private authService: MsalService, // This is already handling MSAL
    private msalBroadcastService: MsalBroadcastService
  ) {
    this.msalApp = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    this.initializeMsal();
  }

  private async initializeMsal(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.msalApp.initialize();
      await this.msalApp.handleRedirectPromise();
      this.isMsalInitialized = true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('MSAL initialization error:', error);
    }
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        filter(status => status === InteractionStatus.None),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: () => this.setLoginDisplay(),
        error: (error) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          console.error('Error during subscription:', error);
        }
      });
  }

  async setLoginDisplay() {
    if (!this.isMsalInitialized) {
      await this.initializeMsal();
    }
    if (!this.localAuthService.isLogin) {
    console.log(this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts());
      const accounts = await this.msalApp.getAllAccounts();
      this.loginDisplay = accounts.length > 0;
      if (this.loginDisplay) {
        const data = accounts[0];
        // Further processing...
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._destroying$.next();
    this._destroying$.complete();
  }
}


No errors appear in the console, and the configurations and initializations appear to be unchanged besides the library upgrade. I suspect this might be a lifecycle or configuration issue with MSAL 3.0 in Angular 17. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or knows of any breaking changes in MSAL 3.0 that could affect account retrieval?


I was able to obtain the user account details after successfully logging in with the code below.
Code :
src/app/auth.service.ts :
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PublicClientApplication, AuthError, AccountInfo } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { msalConfig } from './auth-config';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  private app: PublicClientApplication;
  private isMsalInitialized: boolean = false;

  constructor(private msalService: MsalService) {
    this.app = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    this.initializeMsal();
  }
  private async initializeMsal(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.app.initialize();
      await this.app.handleRedirectPromise();
      this.isMsalInitialized = true; 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('MSAL initialization error:', error);
    }
  }
  async login(): Promise<void> {
    if (!this.isMsalInitialized) {
      await this.initializeMsal();
    }
    try {
      const loginResponse = await this.app.loginPopup({
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'User.Read'],
      });
      console.log('Login successful', loginResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AuthError) {
        console.error('Authentication error:', error.errorMessage);
      } else {
        console.error('Unexpected error during login:', error);
      }
    }
  }
  logout(): void {
    this.app.logout();
  }
  async getUserAccounts(): Promise<AccountInfo[] | null> {
    if (!this.isMsalInitialized) {
      await this.initializeMsal();
    }
    try {
      const accounts = await this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts();
      return accounts;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving accounts:', error);
      return null;
    }
  }
}

src/app/sso/sso.component.ts :
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth.service';
import { AccountInfo } from '@azure/msal-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sso',
  templateUrl: './sso.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sso.component.css'],
})
export class SsoComponent {
  userAccounts: AccountInfo[] | null = null;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.userAccounts = await this.authService.getUserAccounts();
  }
  login(): void {
    this.authService.login();
  }
  logout(): void {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
}

auth-config.ts :
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: '<client_ID>',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
    },
  };

package.json :
"@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.17",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^3.14.0",

I added the following URL in the Azure AD Authentication as a Single-page application, as shown below:
http://localhost:4200


Output :

Browser Output :


I successfully signed in and received my account details, as demonstrated below.


I have updated the code and tried same, but sill I get empty in
console.log(this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts());

@virendra parade Here is my GitHub repo, try it once.

@virendraparade Have you tried my GitHub repo?
